# document.onmousemove only handled by the last created object of my js class

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onmousemove

I'm trying to create a class of movable elements, I get two `this.functions` in, my `clique` function work well for each child's of the class but my `maousemauve` related to a `mousemove` event work only for the last created object.

I think the problem came from the `document.onmousemove = this.maousemauve` declaration which does not include the `this.` statement, but I didn't find how to do else, is it even possible to do what I want to do with the class constructor or am I seeking in the wrong way?

```js
//déclaration de classe, entre parenthéses, les paramètres "inconnus"qui me permettront de définir rapidement mes futurs objets!
class Domino {

  constructor(id, side1, side2, c) {
    this.id = id;
    this.side1 = side1;
    this.side2 = side2;
    this.lien = document.getElementById(id);
    this.c = c;


    this.clique = (event) => {
      this.c += 1;


      this.lien.style.position = 'absolute';



      if (this.c === 2) {
        this.c = 0;
        console.log(this);
        return this.c;
      }

      console.log(this.c);
      return this.c;

    }


    this.maousemauve = (event) => {
      if (this.c === 1) {
        console.log(this.c);
        this.lien.style.left = event.clientX - 50 + 'px';
        this.lien.style.top = event.clientY - 30 + 'px';
      }
    }


    this.lien.onclick = this.clique;
    this.lien.onmousemove = this.maousemauve;

  }
}

var d1 = new Domino("d1", 0, 1, 0);
var d2 = new Domino("d2", 0, 1, 0);
var d3 = new Domino("d3", 0, 1, 0);


console.log(d1);
console.log(d2);
console.log(d3);
```

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}


/*j'utilise les propriétés flex pour aligner les mots au centre dans mes dominos!*/

#d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#d3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <br /><br />
  <div id="d1"> d1 </div>
  <div id="d2"> d2 </div>
  <div id="d3"> d3 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I setted the "document.onmousemove = maousemauve" on "this.lien.onmousemove" and all my domino's are working but if i'm moving my cursor to fast, the domino will not follow the cursor, is there a way to say to the cursor to don't get out of current object with event?

Comment: i'd finally find the solution, i use to declare my "document.onmousemove = function" statement in the declaration of the constructor, and it didn't worked well, finally i'd thought about put it in my "click event" loop so like this, each time the move function is set on true, the javascript is listening for the mousemove event! https://codepen.io/thibault-cabanes/pen/MLYWYw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read in your comments that you apparently found a solution by yourself... that did not work well.

So here's some tips:

- Use [`Element#addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `Element#onXXX` properties for setting events.
- Add a property (`Domino#isMoving` in my example) which will allow you to know if your element is currently moving. (Maybe `Domino#c` was that one in your code, but I was not sure.)
- The `click` event will reverse the `isMoving` value. Then, it will add a `mousemove` event if `isMoving === true`, or will remove it if not. The event need to be attached to the `document`, or your issue: "*if i'm moving my cursor to fast, the domino will not follow the cursor*" will not be corrected.

Check at that simplified example:

```js
class Domino {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.lien = document.getElementById(id);
    
    // Allows to know if the domino is moving or not.
    this.isMoving = false;
    
    this.lien.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.listenOnClick(e);
    });
  }
  
  listenOnClick(e) {
    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      this.listenOnMouseMove(e);
    };
  
    this.lien.style.position = 'absolute';
    
    // If not moving, it is moving...
    // Or if it's moving, it's not moving!
    this.isMoving = !this.isMoving;
    
    // If it's moving, add an event listener on the document when the mouse is moving
    if (this.isMoving) {
      // Attachs the listener on document, because the mouse is *always* on the document. So even if the mouse is outside the domino, it will move.
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    } // Or if it's not, remove that event.
    else {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    }
  }
  
  listenOnMouseMove(e) {
    if (this.isMoving) {
      this.lien.style.left = e.clientX - 50 + 'px';
      this.lien.style.top = e.clientY - 30 + 'px';
    }
  }
}

let d1 = new Domino('d1');
  d2 = new Domino('d2');
```

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}

.domino {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="d1" class="domino">d1</div>
  <div id="d2" class="domino">d2</div>
</body>
```

Comment: To remove an event listener, you need a *reference*  to that function.